# Adding image to a Button in JavaFX after Button is created

Tags: java, button, javafx, imageview, minesweeper

I am working on coding a MineSweeper game using JavaFx. I am having an issue with changing the Buttons to just include an image and not have text. A portion of my code is as follows:

```
ImageView bomb;
Image bombImage = new Image(MineSweeper.class.getResourceAsStream("images/bomb.png"));
bomb = new ImageView(bombImage);
boolean[][] mineField = new boolean[row][column];
for (int i = 0; i < numMines; i++) {
    int indexRow = isMine.nextInt(row);
    int indexCol = isMine.nextInt(column);
    System.out.println("row: " + indexRow + ", column: " + indexCol);
    mineField[indexRow][indexCol] = true;
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        System.out.println("" + mineField[i][j]);
        if (mineField[i][j] == true) {
            board[i][j].setText("");
            board[i][j].setGraphic(bomb);


        } else {
            board[i][j].setText("Nope!");
        }

    }
}
```

This is not how the actual game will work. But I was wanting to check if I could add the image of the bomb to the buttons that contain a mine. When I run the code there is only one image of a mine that shows up and the other buttons just have empty text or say "Nope!." If I cannot figure out how to add an image to a button then I will not be able to actually continue with the programming of the game. I have decided that I want to build this game from scratch and not use Scene Builder. I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for only one image is displayed that you cannot use the same `ImageView` as [graphic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicProperty) for two `Button` objects.

> An optional icon for the Labeled. This can be positioned relative to
>   the text by using
>   setContentDisplay(javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay). The node
>   specified for this variable cannot appear elsewhere in the scene
>   graph, otherwise the IllegalArgumentException is thrown. See the class
>   description of Node for more detail.

Modify this line ...

```
board[i][j].setGraphic(bomb);
```

... to ...

```
board[i][j].setGraphic(new ImageView(bombImage ));
```

This will create a new `ImageView` object for all of your `Button`s.